# ping: : Name or service not known - while pinging a valid ip

Tags: linux, bash, docker, openstack, packer

Well, This appears to be a known issue to many but I've applied many of the workarounds I found online but none of them worked!

I'm running packer from a docker container to build an image on openstack. I could get the ip address of the instance but couldn't ping/ssh/execute ansible within packer provisioners.

All of them fail with this error:

> openstack: ping: 172.30.16.165: Name or service not known

Funny thing is I could ping the same ip from other machines and the docker container executing packer. So, not sure why the packer provisioner couldn't do. DNS & network settings of the host & docker container are all same.

Also, I could connect to other floating ips on the same openstack tenant. I'm using floating-ip-network to assign to an external ip to connect to the instance at a later point.

```
{
      "type": "shell",
      "expect_disconnect": "true",
      "inline": [                
        "echo Rebooting...",
        "sudo -u root /sbin/init 6"        
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",      
      "pause_before": "60s",
      "inline": [
        "echo waiting for 60s"               
      ]
    },        
    {
      "type": "shell-local",      
      "inline": [
        "ping -c 4 $(cat /tmp/ipaddress)"            
      ]
    }
```

I did add the ip to `/etc/hosts` file but it didn't fix the issue. If someone could help me with this, it would be really great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add output of `hexdump -C /tmp/ipaddress` to your question.

Comment: Hey Cyrus, may thanks. Yeah, somehow there are hidden characters in `/tmp/ipaddress` file. Now, I've got rid of them and all is fine. 
`cat -v /tmp/ipaddress` showed all the hidden characters. 
Your help is much appreciated! Many Thanks again.. :)